# Checking if A follows B on twitter using Tweepy/Python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have a list of a few thousand twitter ids and I would like to check who follows who in this network.

I  used Tweepy to get the accounts using something like:

```
ids = {}
for i in list_of_accounts:
    for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, screen_name=i).pages():
            ids[i]=page
            time.sleep(60)
```

The values in the dictionary ids form the network I would like to analyze. If I try to get the complete list of followers for each id (to compare to the list of users in the network) I run into two problems.

The first is that I may not have permission to see the user's followers - that's okay and I can skip those - but they stop my program. This is the case with the following code:

```
connections = {}
for x in user_ids:
    l=[]
    for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, user_id=x).pages():
        l.append(page)
    connections[x]=l
```

The second is that I have no way of telling when my program will need to sleep to avoid the rate-limit. If I put a 60 second wait after every page in this query - my program would take too long to run.

I tried to find a simple 'exists_friendship' command that might get around these issues in a simpler way - but I only find things that became obsolete with the change to API 1.1. I am open to using other packages for Python. Thanks.

Comment: Is `page` a single user id or a list of ids?

Answer (score 0):

```
if api.exists_friendship(userid_a, userid_b):
    print "a follows b"
else:
    print "a doesn't follow b, check separately if b follows a"
```